# How to append data in a webservice retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

i am trying to get json response from my web service. For that i need to append the data in the url and get the response. I successfully did it with volley.

But now i am trying to do the same with retrofit. But i am confused on the appending part as the url is divided in the main activity and the interface.

Here is how i did it in volley.

```
String uri = String.format("http://walletuncle.com/myservice.asmx/UserLogin?UserId=%1$s&password=%2$s",
            username,
            password);
```

Comment: Are you getting data from that link?
Because it's broken, you changed one datatype as I see.

Comment: yes the link worked fine with volley i just had to append userid and password manually